# How to use join on a result of another join with a new field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

i have 2 tables vehicle1 which contains details of different types of vehicle and have a unique lot_ and another table wishlist which have two fields lot# and a userid 
what im trying to do is return a vehicle1 table with an extra field say flag added to it with values either 1 or 0 corresponding to if the userid has added that vehicle into wishlist or not 
i've used this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_AllVehicleModified]
@user varchar(50),
@limit varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ad.*
FROM ( 
SELECT *,CASE WHEN t1.lot# IN (t2.lot_) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Flag
FROM  vehicle1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN wishlist t2 ON t1.lot#=t2.lot_ WHERE t2.userid=@user ) ad
ORDER BY lot#
OFFSET  (@limit - 1)*10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
END
```

this query contains a result with a new field flag containing 1 and only those vehicles which were in wishlist
however i want the whole vehicle1 table which contains 0 in the remaining 
how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want a `left join` and conditional logic:

```
select v.*, case when w.lot# is null then 0 else 1 end flag
from vehicle v
left join whishlist w on w.userid = @user and w.lot# = v.lot_
```

You can easily integrate this query in your stored procedure and add the row-limiting clause.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT v.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM wishlist wl
                          WHERE v.lot# = wl.lot_ AND
                                wl.userid = @user
                         )
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as Flag
FROM vehicle1 v
ORDER BY v.lot#
OFFSET (@limit - 1)*10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I think it better captures the logic that you want.  I also suspect that it might work better with `ORDER BY` and `FETCH`.